# How to inject a "Broken pipe" error?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I am running test for a network program which uses TCP sockets. To verify a bug fix, I need to reproduce a "Broken pipe" error at the socket layer, but I don't know how. Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Broken pipe' means that you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer. So, have the peer close the connection.

Comment: Yes, in theory. In my code, I try to quit the receiver by close(), exit() and even "ctrl-C". Nothing will make the sender print "Broken pipe" error.

Comment: Send some more. Nobody said it would be instantaneous. It can't happen in the first send after the breakage, for example, because of TCP buffering. Also the sender won't necessarily print anything unless it is programmed to do so on every send() error.

Comment: Yes, I send with a large piece of data and slow down the network, during transmission kill the receiver. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A "Broken pipe" error message generally comes from the shell when it detects that a child it created has exited due to a SIGPIPE signal.  So you can may be able to cause one manually by killing a child with a SIGPIPE (`kill -PIPE %1` to kill the first background command).

SIGPIPE is generated by the kernel and sent to any process that tries to write to a pipe or socket after the other end has been closed.

Comment: I have the code checking the return value of "send()", and use "perror()" to print error. If it is a real "Broken pipe", perror will print it out. But for your method, the program quits without printing any error.

Comment: Then you have a missing test somewhere, or the program has already sent most of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and couldn't find a procedure documented anywhere, so here you go.

I found a server in my ssh config that uses an 'nc' proxy command.

> host server
>
> > ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -4 -n -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:55555 %h %p

I ran an ssh with ServerAlive options set to 1:

> > ssh  -o ServerAliveInterval=1 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 e3prosup@server

Then in a different session, I found the 'nc' process associated with the ssh and  killed it.  Both kill -9 (SIGKILL) or kill -13 (SIGPIPE) will work.

> > ps -efa
>
> > e3prosup 19502 10955  0 11:43 pts/6    00:00:00 ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=1 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 e3prosup@server
> >
> > e3prosup 19503 19502  0 11:43 pts/6    00:00:00 /usr/bin/nc -4 -n -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:55555 server 22
>
> > kill -13 19503

Now the ssh session gets:

> > e3prosup@server> Write failed: Broken pipe

Comment: There is not one word about `ssh` in the question.